# How can I destructure an instant and extract year, month, etc from java-time library

Tags: clojure, java-time

I'm trying to destructure an `instant` and get year, month, day.

I've tried with `java-time/as` function without success.

```
(ns myproject.time-test
  (:require [java-time :as jt])
  (:gen-class))

(def curr-time (jt/instant (System/currentTimeMillis)))

(jt/as curr-time :year)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't know how to write the answer in clojure-style but you will need to convert the instant to a `ZonedDateTime` by using a `ZoneId`. The converted object will then give you values like year etc. (specific for a time zone).

Comment: Any good reason not to use clj-time?

Comment: @slipset If you read `clj-time` readme you'll see.

Comment: @akond hmm, hadn’t seen that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it without the `..` to make it clear you are using Java interop (it appears that clojure.java-time has no wrapper to convert from an Instant to a ZonedDateTime:

```
(-> (jt/instant)
    (.atZone (ZoneId/systemDefault))  ; => java ZonedDateTime obj
    (.getYear))

 => 2018
```

There are other ways which may be useful:

```
(jt/zoned-date-time)              => #object[java.time.ZonedDateTime 0x2585437a 
                                     "2018-07-19T11:42:37.093731-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]"]

(jt/year (jt/zoned-date-time))    => #object[java.time.Year 0x74694f06 "2018"]
(jt/year)                         => #object[java.time.Year 0x16c69c47 "2018"]
```

and also

```
(jt/as (jt/zoned-date-time) :year :month-of-year :day-of-month)   =>   (2018 7 19)
```

Another way to convert an `Instant` to a `ZonedDateTime`:

```
  (let [zdt (ZonedDateTime/ofInstant (jt/instant) (ZoneId/systemDefault))]
    (.getYear zdt)         => 2018
    (.getMonth zdt)        => #object[java.time.Month 0x403d9a5b "JULY"]
    (.getDayOfMonth zdt)   => 19
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(ns mastering.stackoverflow
    (:import
        (java.time ZoneId)))

    (.. (jt/instant)
            (atZone (ZoneId/systemDefault))
            (getYear))
```

Other methods like `getMonthValue`, `getMinute` are also available.

You could do "extraction" that way:

```
(let [i       (.. (jt/instant)
                (atZone (ZoneId/systemDefault)))
      extract (juxt (memfn getYear) (memfn getMinute))]
    (extract i))

; => [2018 37]
```